# particular images position for all android devices

Tags: android

```
I am developing an android board game in which images can be dragged. I want to put images on particular position when the game starts and position should remain same on each device. I am using Linear layout and absolute layout. I have calculated screen width and apply formula,position of image and use set X() and set Y() but still it is not working. Position changed when i run application. need help please.
```

his is xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bk"
android:id="@+id/LLayout"
>

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:id="@+id/absLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="0dp"
            android:layout_y="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dice" />
          <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_x="0dp"
            android:layout_y="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dice" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is .java:
When i add values in setX() and setY() it does not display images on correct point. Moreover i want the images should keep same position even on different devices that is why i am calculating position according to screen density.

```
public class MoveImagesOnTouchActivity extends Activity{
    ImageView img=null;
    ImageView img2=null;
    AbsoluteLayout aLayout;
    Point point;
    int status=0;
    int width;
    int height;
    int x,y,x2,y2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        width = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        height = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        //Toast.makeText(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this, " width is : "+width+ "height is :"+height , 50000).show();    

        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        aLayout= (AbsoluteLayout)findViewById(R.id.absLayout);
        x= (9*width)/100;
        y= (80*height)/100;
        img.setX(x);
        img.setY(y);
        x2=(143*width)/100;
        y2= (80*height)/100;
        img2.setX(x2);
        img2.setY(y2);

        img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                status=1;
                Log.i("ImageStatus",""+status);

                int[] values= new int[2];
                img.getLocationOnScreen(values);
                //img.getLocationInWindow(values);
                int x = values[0];
                int y = values[1] ;
                //Toast.makeText(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this, " x is : "+x+ "y :"+y , 500).show();   

                return false;       
            }
        });
        img2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                status=2;
                Log.i("ImageStatus",""+status);

                int[] values= new int[2];
                img2.getLocationOnScreen(values);
                //img.getLocationInWindow(values);
                int x2 = values[0];
                int y2 = values[1] ;
                Toast.makeText(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this, " x2 is : "+x2+ "y2 :"+y2 , 5000).show();    
                return false;
            }
        });
        aLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("touch",""+event);

                if(status==1) // any event from down and move
                {
                    //img.setX((9*width)/100);
                    //img.setY((80*height)/100);
                    //img.setY((80*height)/100);
                    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)event.getX()-img.getWidth()/2,(int)event.getY()-img.getHeight()/2);
                    img.setLayoutParams(lp);

                }
                if(status==2) // any event from down and move
                {
                    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)event.getX()-img2.getWidth()/2,(int)event.getY()-img2.getHeight()/2);
                    img2.setLayoutParams(lp);

                }
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    status=0;


                    img.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    img2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say the "same on each devices"   Do all devices you are working with have exactly the same screen size and density?

Comment: I think you need to show what you have done and include a graphic of what you are expecting to happen. LinearLayout should do what you want. There should be no need to compute any actual screen positions if you are using weights.

Comment: here is my code. kindly have a look i hope you will help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For setting image position you can use

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB  ) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    params.leftMargin = (int) 50; // use your value
    params.topMargin = (int) 50;  
    mImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
}else{
    // your setX() and setY()   
}
```

You need to specify for lower versions than **HONEYCOMB**

In My Case I am trying to set position for layout using below

```
     /**
     * @param Relative-Layout layout for set position
     * @param height [preous layout height
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void setLayoutXY(LinearLayout linearLayout, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB  ) {
            // only for lower version than honeycomb
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
            params.topMargin = height; 
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        else{
            linearLayout.setY(height);
        }
    }
```

It might be helpful for you

**Check Edited Code**

```
package com.example.stacktest;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MoveImagesOnTouchActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView img = null;
    ImageView img2 = null;
    AbsoluteLayout aLayout;
    Point point;
    int status = 0;
    int width;
    int height;
    int x, y, x2, y2;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        width = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        height = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        // Toast.makeText(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this, " width is : "+width+
        // "height is :"+height , 50000).show();

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        aLayout = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.absLayout);
        x = (9 * width) / 100;
        y = (80 * height) / 100;

        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, x, y);
        img.setLayoutParams(params);
//      img.setX(x);
//      img.setY(y);
        x2 = (143 * width) / 100;
        y2 = (80 * height) / 100;

        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, x2, y2);
        img2.setLayoutParams(params1);
//      img2.setX(x2);
//      img2.setY(y2);

        img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                status = 1;
                Log.i("ImageStatus", "" + status);

                int[] values = new int[2];
                img.getLocationOnScreen(values);
                // img.getLocationInWindow(values);
                int x = values[0];
                int y = values[1];
                // Toast.makeText(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this, " x is : "+x+
                // "y :"+y , 500).show();

                return false;
            }
        });
        img2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                status = 2;
                Log.i("ImageStatus", "" + status);

                int[] values = new int[2];
                img2.getLocationOnScreen(values);
                // img.getLocationInWindow(values);
                int x2 = values[0];
                int y2 = values[1];
                Toast.makeText(MoveImagesOnTouchActivity.this,
                        " x2 is : " + x2 + "y2 :" + y2, 5000).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        aLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("touch", "" + event);
                if (status == 1) // any event from down and move
                {
                    // img.setX((9*width)/100);
                    // img.setY((80*height)/100);
                    // img.setY((80*height)/100);
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)event.getY()-img.getHeight()/2, (int) event.getX() - img.getWidth() / 2);
//                  params.topMargin = (int)event.getY()-img.getHeight()/2;
//                  params.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - img.getWidth() / 2;
                    img.setLayoutParams(params);
                    // LayoutParams lp = new
                    // LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,(int)event.getX()-img.getWidth()/2,(int)event.getY()-img.getHeight()/2);
                    // img.setLayoutParams(lp);
                }
                if (status == 2) // any event from down and move
                {
//                  LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(
//                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
//                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int) event.getX()
//                                  - img2.getWidth() / 2, (int) event.getY()
//                                  - img2.getHeight() / 2);
//                  img2.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams params = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (int)event.getY()-img.getHeight()/2, (int) event.getX() - img.getWidth() / 2);
//                  params.topMargin = (int)event.getY()-img.getHeight()/2;
//                  params.leftMargin = (int) event.getX() - img.getWidth() / 2;
                    img2.setLayoutParams(params);

                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    status = 0;

                    img.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    img2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: please have a look on my code. I have searched a lot but i cannot find any solution.

Comment: it does not work for me i think something is wrong here in OnCreate() :
 int[] values = new int[2];
        img.getLocationOnScreen(values);
        int x = values[0];
        int y = values[1];
       x = (192 * width) / 100;
       y = (392 * height) / 100;
       LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, x, y);
       img.setLayoutParams(params);
why image change its position even after specifying location before drag. I have calculated screen dimension and image position then set image but it still change its location :(

Comment: LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, x, y);
img.setLayoutParams(params);
Image disappear when i use this code after getting x and y position of image.

Comment: You are working with absolute layout which is deprecated.  Try to use linear or relative. I checked code and working

Comment: Now i am using linear layout but in layout Params i could not able to put x and y values. Can you tell me how can i set values of x and y in layout params
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,x,y);
img.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: You can use this . which will cause layout position from left & top  

linearLayout.getLayoutParams().height = heightfromtopinpixel;
  linearLayout.getLayoutParams().width = widthfromleftinpixel;

Comment: i used relative layout but now dragged images get smaller near boundary. I think i have to set boundary limit so that image can move only in restrict area?

Comment: Yes. You have to fix x y . As per position you want